# Asp.Net Publishing Issue

Tags: asp.net, publishing-site

I am publishing my website in asp.net but i am in a small problem i will explain you my problem with screenshot

This is my Solution Explorer as you see I have 2 ApprovalListing pages one in my Employee Folder and Other in my Order Folder

[image]

Now i publish my website using Publish Wizard and used ***Use Fixed naming and Single Page Assemblies***

[image]

and Now the problem is as i have told you i have 2 ApprovalListing in my Solution and when i publish my website which dll is my EmloyeeApprovalListing and OrderApprovalListing. Can any 1 point out how can i check that out ?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Open each corresponding aspx page and look at the reference on the top. It will say which DLL is used by each page.

For example, one page will say something like:

```
...inherits="ApprovalListing, App_Web_about.aspx.cdcab7d2" %>
```

where `cdcab7d2` will correspond to one of the DLLs